# eval() alternative for calculator

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm designing a simple calculator with HTML & JavaScript. Essentially, when the "equals" button is clicked, the expression the user entered with the calculator buttons is stored in a string variable, `userInput`, and  `eval(userInput)` gets the answer. Is there an alternative way to calculate the result without using `eval()`?

**Update:**

Thanks for the comments,

```
function calculateStr(userInput) {
    return new Function('return ' + equation)();
}

calculateStr(userInput)
```

works well.

Comment: Sure just parse the expression and calculate the result.

Comment: This is bordering on too broad for an answer but in general yes of course there is otherwise computer programming languages wouldnt be a thing. It involves parsing your equation and executing the result. Or just use mathjs: http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Comment: There are many questions matching the search ["\[js\] evaluate expression without eval"](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+evaluate+expression+without+eval), surely one or more answer this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, cool, a search page as dupe target :)